# PHP script for using the on duplicate key update with random numbers

Tags: php

I have a php script of student form.

Am making use of d on duplicate key update function.

I automatically assign unique primary key 2 users after records have been saved..

My query 2 assign numbers is like this.

```
$length=(10000000,99999999);
$random=substr(uniqid,0,$length);
```

A short save and update query..

```
$save="insert into student(Reg_number,username ,password,surname and so on)
VALUES('$random','$username','$password','$surname' nd so on)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='$username' ";

$result=mysql_query($save)or die(mysql_error());
```

This is my problem, because I automatically assign random Unique numbers after a record has been saved.

Which works perfectly, but when I try to update the same record, a new random number is generated and thus it saves as a new record.so the on duplicate key update is never implemented because the random is newly generated and it will save again.

But if I specify the id number, let's say

```
Insert into student(reg_number, username, password)
Values(1234ac, $username, $password)
On duplicate key update Username = $username.
```

This query works perfectly because number is fixed and its sees that present record. But have no idea how to make it work with the random number.

Comment: why are you not using the db provided auto increment field?

Comment: While you say "it saves as a new record", I think your table definition is not correct. Make column `"username"` unique.

Comment: The unique field there is reg_number..the $random is used to assign unique numbers to that field in the database which is reg_number. Am doing an online admission system nd am using dat field reg_nunber 2 reference d student rather than auto incremented value

Comment: you shouldn't be changing usernames like that. and generating random numbers can be problematic. you'll end up generating a duplicate number much sooner and more frequently than you think possible. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: 2 me nd 2 others your sentences are difficult 2 read